# java и .net на одной машине

Tags: .net, java

Всем доброго времени суток.
Я уже в течении 2 лет разрабатываю для веб на .net (asp.net + iis + ms + sql server)
cчас начался один проект на java (gwt), вот собственно как лучше создать виртуальную машину и на ней установить все для java(tom cat, my sql server и т.д), или все можно поставить рядом с .net и все будет работать хорошо на одной машине? интересно мнения из вашего опыта 
заранее спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 года работаете и нету понятия, какие могут быть проблемы?

1. Ставьте, конечно, все вместе.
2. Если будут конфликты или переназначьте сервера на другой порт, или какой-то из них "тушите".

Comment: а ms sql server и mysql конфликтовать не будут?

Comment: нет, у меня работают нормально, вроде бы они по умолчанию на разных портах, но если и будут - там легко найти настройки смены порта